# Shortcut in intellij to create resource folder with same path as of Java file in main or test section

Tags: intellij-idea

Let's say if I am writing a test in folder structure of 
test/com/abc/xyz/mysql/departments/employee/permission/TestAdmin.java

Is there a short cut to create resource file in same directory structure. Currently I have to create all the folders indivisually.

resources/com/abc/xyz/mysql/departments/employee/permission/mydef.features

key combination or fastest way. Like ctrl + shift + T create test file in same directory path in "test"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No :(

For tests, there is a specific intention named `Create Test` (under `Settings->Intentions->Java->Declaration` defined in IntelliJ by default which creates the test in the same folder and is bound to Ctrl+Shift+T, but there is no intention to create resources in the same manner.